# Read all check box fields true from sObject?

Tags: apex, soql

How to read all `checkbox=true` fields from sObject in soql query? Here is my query:

```
List<Sample__c> lst = [
    SELECT summary__c,status__c,priority__c,issuetype__c,updated__c
    FROM Sample__c WHERE ...
];
```

What should I pass in my `WHERE` condition for getting all check box fields true?

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like any other where filter

`where chackbox1__c = true AND checkbox2__c = true AND checkbox3__c = true AND .....`

Since your query is not dynamic (a query string and then database.query) this would be your option.

In order to be more dynamic you would have to construct your query string using the describe methods to get the checkbox field names and add them to the filter part of your query.

If this is what you would like to do please update your question

Comment: i have different checkbox fields in Sample__c object so i need to query all checkbox fields are true so is there anyway to read fields instead of each field mentioning as like this here chackbox1__c = true AND checkbox2__c = true AND checkbox3__c = true AND .....